# JAVA Dropwizard configuration for Neo4j ogm

Tags: java, configuration, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, dropwizard

I'm building a project in JAVA with Dropwizard and are looking to start using Neo4j as database. I have been looking on a lot of different options and think that the **spring-data-neo4j** lib looks like a good solution.

However, since I haven't been working with Spring earlier, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to setup the configuration classes in order to start building **repositoris/DAO's**.

I have found a tutorial for integrating **springs MySQL-driver**, but while reading through the documentation for **springs neo4j-driver**, I noticed that the neo4j-driver doesn't seem to use the **DataSourceFactory** establishing a connection.

Anyone have any idea on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you aren't tied to the idea of Dropwizard then I would recommend using Spring Boot with Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) as it's a bit more closely integrated. AFAIK there is only community support for Dropwizard and Spring so if things get difficult it's going to be harder to fix. That said, if you want to build your own integration you can use the Neo4j-OGM directly (SDN uses this) and make it work with Dropwizard. Also Neo4j isn't a relational database so JDBC concepts like `DataSourceFactory` aren't applicable here.

Comment: @digx1 the reason why I chose **DW** is that the company I'm working at are using it, so I want to get a better understanding of the underlying mechanics of **DW** for work while building my own project.
Alright, didn't know that the `DataSourceFactory` was strictly for relational databases, I thought about building a small lib for it on my own, but thought that might be unnecessary.